# Almost everywhere bounded function

Tags: lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

Let $\psi$ be measurable function such that for all $ f \in L^{1}(\mu)$, $ f\psi \in L^{1}(\mu)$. Then $\psi$ is bounded almost everywhere(in sense of measure $\mu$).

My attempt:
Use contraposition: if $\psi $ isn't bounded everywhere then $\forall M>0$, there exists a set $A$ such that $\mu (A)>0 $ and $ \psi(x) > M , \forall x \in A$. Now i need to prove that there is an $f \in L^{1} $ such that $ f\psi \not\in L^{1} $. But I don't know how.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you rather mean $\psi(x)>M$ $\forall x\in A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove this statement using Baire Category argument. But here, I will argue by contrapositive showing that
$$
\psi \notin L^\infty(\mu) \implies \exists f\in L^1(\mu) \  :  \ f\psi\notin L^1(\mu).
$$ Let $E_j =\{ 2^j\le |\psi|<2^{j+1}\}$ and $c_j = \mu (E_j).$ Note that assumption implies $c_j>0$ for infinitely many $j$'s. Define $J=\{j:c_j>0\}$ and $$
f(x) = \sum_{j\in J} \frac{1}{c_j \sqrt{2}^{j}} 1_{E_j}(x).
$$ Then $\int |f|=\int f =\sum_{j\in J} 2^{-j/2}<\infty$. However,
$$
|\psi(x)||f(x)| \ge 2^j\frac{1}{c_j \sqrt{2}^{j}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}^{j}}{c_j}
$$ on each $E_j, \ j\in J$, which implies
$$
\int |\psi f|=\sum_{j\in J} \int_{E_j} |\psi f| \ge \sum_{j\in J}\int_{E_j}\frac{\sqrt{2}^{j}}{c_j}=\sum_{j\in J} \sqrt{2}^j =\infty.
$$ Thus $\psi f\notin L^1(\mu)$ and the claim is proved.

Comment: How do you know that measure of $E_{j}$ is positive ,they might be empty sets for some $j$

Comment: @Mark Oops, you are absolutely right. I was silly. It should have been stated as there exist infinitely many $j$ such that $c_j>0$. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Was this originally your idea or you did some similar problem ?

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure about my memory, but maybe I learnt this or similar argument somewhere. The idea behind this argument is to find a sequence $\alpha_j>0$ such that $\sum_j \alpha_j 2^j c_j =\infty$ while $\sum_j \alpha_j c_j$ is bounded. Then define $f = \sum_j \alpha_j 1_{E_j}$. (Here $\alpha_j = 2^{-j/2}(1/c_j)$.)